# mean() returns NaN for subset of dataframe

Tags: r

I'm getting a NaN result for mean(group2$score). I'm trying to create a function to list descriptive statistics for my data.

```
printf <- function (...) {
    cat(sprintf(...))
}

data <- data.frame(
    id <- c(1:200),
    group <- c(replicate(100, 1), replicate(100, 2)),
    score <- rnorm(200, mean = 100, sd = 15)
)

descriptives <- function (data) {
    group1 <- data[data$group <= 100, ]
    group2 <- data[data$group >= 101, ]
    printf("group 1 mean: %.2f\n", mean(group1$score))
    printf("group 2 mean: %.2f\n", mean(group2$score)) #this is where the NaN gets printed
}

descriptives(data)
```

Comment: note that in `group` you only have 1's and 2's and you are asking for subsetting using `data$group <= 100` and `data$group >= 101`, therefore all your data belongs to `group1` and none of them to `group2`, that's why R is returning `NaN` for `mean(group2$score)`

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you have a look at the [R-FAQ on calculating mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061) and using one of those methods rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, just realised that I used `$group` when I was meant to use `$id`. Always easier to see mistakes after posting in a public space!

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that there is no data in that subset.

```
mean(numeric(0))
[1] NaN
```

This is definitely the case with your data as the group variable is either 1 or 2 and you are trying to split them on a value of 100.